# Riemann Surface of $z^3$

Tags: riemann-surfaces

I'm new to the topic of Riemann surfaces and complex analysis, and I tried to compute the Riemann surface of $z^3$ on Wolfram Alpha but couldn't because its not a multivalued function. How can I compute the riemann surface of $z^3$ or I got something really wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When thinking of the Riemann surface of an *expression* with one complex variable, you should really think of converting that into an *equation* with two complex variables, like this:
$$w = z^3
$$
The resulting Riemann surface is then the solution set of this equation:
$$S = \{(w,z) \in \mathbb C^2 \mid w=z^3\}
$$
However, as you have observed, $w=z^3$ is single valued as a function of the variable $z$. So that equation *defines* a function with independent variable $z$ and dependent variable $w$. Also $S$ is simply the graph of this function (with domain--codomain variables switched from their usual "first--last" positions). So as is usual with functions, we obtain an isomorphism between the domain of the function and the graph of the function, namely $\mathbb C \mapsto S$ given by $z \mapsto (w,z^3)$. In this context "isomorphism" means "biholomorphism" and so the Riemann surface is (biholomorphic to) $\mathbb C$.

Comment: But still there must be a sheet that contains the results of the equation right, because I've seen someone plotting a Riemann surface for w=z^2+1.

Comment: OP wrote $z^3$, and you wrote $z^2$, but what you wrote applies to $z^3$ as well

Comment: Oops, thanks for that

Comment: Now what happens if we consider $S$ the other way around ... $w=z^3$ thought of as $z = w^{1/3}$.  In this case, the same set $S$ and the same Riemann surface is thought of as a $3$-fold covering of the $w$-plane.  When you say "the Riemann surface of $z^3$", perhaps that is what is intended.

Comment: @Krcx: Regarding your comment, $w=z^2+1$ also defines $w$ as a function of $z$, and the domain of that function, namely the $z$-plane, is also (identified with) the Riemann surface. Your words regarding a *sheet that contains the results of the equation* are rather vague and I'm not sure how to address them, but whatever those words mean, the point is simply that in the case of an equation $w=f(z)$, the $z$-plane is the thing you want.

Comment: Much thanks to all of you, I am new to the topic and trying to learn it on my own (11th grade) I haven't though of the possibility of switching between w-plane and z-plane therefore I was confused.